# What is LoggingEventData ? How and where should it be used?

Tags: log4net

I wanted to know the difference between LoggingEvent and LoggingEventData , why is LoggingEventData is used, since LoggingEventData is just a portable version of LoggingEvent.

I am writing my own custom layout , Inside this layout members of LoggingEvent are made available to me only after I make a call to GetLoggingEventData() , without the call to this function I get null values to all of the LoggingEvent properties . Could you please tell me why this might be happening?

```
 class MyLayout:LayoutSkeleton
 {
   public override void Format (TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent )
   {
     var initObj = new InitObj(loggingEvent);
   }
 }


Class InitObj {
     public InitObj(LoggingEveng loggingEvent) {
          String xyz = loggingEvent.Properties["xyz"]; 

           // This is null , when

           // There is no call to

           //loggingEvent.GetLoggingEventData();     
     }
}
```

I did take a look into GetLoggingEventData function in LoggingEvent :

```
public LoggingEventData GetLoggingEventData()
{
  return this.GetLoggingEventData(FixFlags.Partial);
}
```

The FixFlags is probably fixing/enabling the loggingevent properties.
I am not very sure about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation for the [LoggingEvent constructor that takes a LoggingEventData instance](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Core.LoggingEventConstructor4.html) says:

> This constructor is provided to allow a LoggingEvent to be created
>   independently of the log4net framework. This can be useful if you
>   require a custom serialization scheme.

There's an example of usage in this [Azure Table Storage appender](http://www.kongsli.net/nblog/2011/08/15/log4net-writing-log-entries-to-azure-table-storage/#comment-509116932)

Comment: Sorry to bother you , I am writing my own custom layout , Inside this layout members of LoggingEvent are made available to me only after I make a call to GetLoggingEventData() , without the call to this function I get null values to all of the LoggingEvent properties . Could you please tell me why this might be happening?